On an application of Stone-Weierstrass Theorem
Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a comapct set and $C(K)$ be the  family of complex-valued continuous functions on $K.$ For $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d,$ define $e_\xi(x)=e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x}, x\in K.$ Then, the set $\mathcal{A}=\{e_\xi(x): \xi\in \mathbb{R}^d\}$ is clear a subagebra of $C(X)$, which contains constants and separate points. So, applying the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem we have $\mathcal{A}$ is uniformly dense in $C(K)$.
Now, let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a set has Lebesgue measure zero. Define $\mathcal{B}=\{e_\xi(x): \xi\in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus E\}$. My question: Is $\mathcal{B}$ uniformly dense in $C(K)$?  The problems are that $\mathcal{B}$ doesn't necessarily contain constants since maybe $0\in E$, and it is also not necessarily a algebra (i.e, if $f,g\in \mathcal{B}$ then $fg\in \mathcal{B}$) now. Any comments will be appreciated!

It suffices to show that $\mathcal B$ is dense in $\mathcal A$. Since $E$ has measure $0$, $\Bbb R^d\setminus E$ is dense in $\Bbb R^d$. Let $\xi\in\Bbb R^d$. Then there are $\xi_n\in \Bbb R^d\setminus E$ such that $\xi_n\to \xi$, and it is not difficult to see that then $e_{\xi_n}\to e_\xi$ uniformly (using that $K$ is bounded), so $\mathcal B$ is dense in $\mathcal A$ and hence in $C(K)$.

1  Thanks. Yes, it is so nice!
